# How to get user's voice to be used as biometric voice identification in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to build an ecosystem where users uses its voice as biometric registration, that implies to get access to user's voice in order to be checked by biometric processes.
Does any body know how can I build that functionality using Dialogflow? How can I get the voice recording?

Regards.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-apple-client/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Google does not provide the audio from a user to Actions. Users can get this through their activity log, but Actions cannot.

However, if you want this for identity purposes, Google is already doing this. If a user has enabled Voice Match on their Google devices, then you can either use [Account Linking with Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) to get the user's Google ID with their permission, or you can put a token of some sort in the [user storage](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data) to determine when the same user has returned in the future.

Comment: Nice approach, unfortunately, I was wondering how to identify a user using external biometric APIs like the one provide by [link mobbeel](https://www.mobbeel.com/en/home/)

Regards.